# DataFrame Groupby while maintaining original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame that has  9 columns which are encoded values for Day of the week(1-7), Week of the Year(1-52), Month of the Year (1-12), Time bin (every 3 hours), Salary Day(0,1) and Holiday(0,1) and Amount(real number). The time is placed in a time bin e.g. 15:00 is placed in 6th time bin and 7:34 is placed in the 3rd time bin.

```
Day Week    Month   Time    Salary  Holiday Amount
1   5       2      1        0       0        700.0
1   5       2      1        0       0        800.0
3   18      5      7        1       0        90.0
```

Basically, I need to group the data by the first 6 columns and create a new column which is the summed value of Amount. However, this amount is will be repeated since I need to maintain the original dataframe. So, it must only sum purchases that have the same Day, Week, Month, Time, Salary and Holiday i.e. sum in that group.

```
Day Week    Month   Time    Salary  Holiday Amount  Sum
1   5       2      1        0       0        700.0   1500.0
1   5       2      1        0       0        800.0   1500.0
3   18      5      7        1       0        90.0    90.0
```

I have grouped the data frame by Day, Week, Month, Time, Salary, Holiday and summed Amount.

```
temp= features.groupby(by=["Day", "Week", "Month", "Time", "Salary", "Holiday"])["Amount"].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` to return a column of the same size of the original data frame, from [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

> The transform method returns an object that is indexed the same (same
>   size) as the one being grouped. Thus, the passed transform function
>   should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk.

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(["Day", "Week", "Month", "Time", "Salary", "Holiday"]).transform('sum')

df    
# Day Week Month Time Salary Holiday Amount  Sum
#0  1   5      2    1      0       0    700 1500
#1  1   5      2    1      0       0    800 1500
#2  3  18      5    7      1       0     90   90
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the index on temp and then do an outer merge with the original feature dataframe on all the columns you grouped by.

```
result = features.merge(temp.reset_index(), on=["Day", "Week", "Month", "Time", "Salary", "Holiday"])
```